# TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined Get value from input print the value in div with angular js

Tags: angularjs

HTML Code

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Ionic Sample ToDoListApp</title>
    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <link href="lib/datepicker-for-ionic/dist/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- path to ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/datepicker-for-ionic/dist/templates.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/datepicker-for-ionic/dist/ionic-datepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ToDoListCtrl">
    <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">Tasks</h1>

    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in toDoListItems " n ng-click="openDodal()">Task {{$index + 1}}</ion-item>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button button-block" ng-click="openModal()">Add Task</button>
        </div>
    </ion-content>

    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-positive">
    </ion-footer-bar>


    <script id="modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
                <h1 class="title">Add New Task</h1>
            </div>
            <br></br>
            <form novalidate>
                <div class="list">
                    <div class="list list-inset" >
                        <label class="item item-input"  id="descriptions">
                            <input type="text" height:"900px" class="description" placeholder="Description ..." ng-model="data.describe" required>
                        </label>
                        <label input="email" class="item item-input" id="email" ng-model="data.email" required >
                            <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                            <input type="email">
                        </label>
                        <label class="item item-input" id="">
                            <span class="input-label">Date</span>
                            <input type="date">
                        </label>     
                    </div>
                                  <button class="button button-block button-balanced" type="submit" ng-click="AddItem(data)">
                        Add Item
                    </button>
                    <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="closeModal()"> cancel</button>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </script>
    <script id="dodal.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <div class="modal">

            <div class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
                <h1 class="title">Task {{$index}}</h1>

            </div>
           <div class="alert alert-info">
               {{great}}
           </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 100%">
                <div style="text-align: center">
                    <form ng-submit="AddItem(data)">
                        <div class="list">
                            <div class="list list-inset">
                                <label class="item item-input" id="description">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" height:"900px" placeholder="Add Note " ng-model="searchText">
                                </label>
                                <button class="button button-block" ng-click="check()">Add Note</button>
                                <button class="button button-block" ng-click="closeDodal()">back</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        </form>

                </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js angularJS

```
angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])

.controller('ToDoListCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal ) {
$scope.toDoListItems = [{

}];
$scope.searchText = " ";

$scope.show = function()
{
    $scope.great = $scope.searchText;
}

$scope.AddItem = function (data) {
$scope.toDoListItems.push({ task: data.describe,status: 'not done' });
```

Above is code for an app I'm building to create tasks.  When I try and Get value from input print the value in div with angular js, I get the following error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'describe' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your array and $scope.data variable before start pushing items onto it

```
$scope.toDoListItems = []; //in the beginning of your controller
$scope.data = {}; //initialize your data object
```

Update your click event to

```
<button class="button button-block button-balanced" type="submit" ng-click="AddItem()">
```

See ng-click event, we don't need to send over the data object here, its unnecessary since we are already managing the state of data in our scope.

and update your AddItem function like

```
$scope.AddItem = function () {
    $scope.toDoListItems.push({ task: $scope.data.describe,status: 'not done' });
    //reset the data variable after insert

    $scope.data = {};
}
```

Comment: And as for my show() function its still not printing my result from the input field in the div

Comment: I don't see where you are calling the show function from? Edit your code to include the required information

Comment: Does it solves the issue you originally posted for, right?

Comment: Yes, the show function in the app.js file is written.  And the button that says ng-click="check()" I changed to ng-click="show()"  and my input field is ng-Modal="searchText"

Comment: This looks a separate concern to me as I still can't see your changes. You have to verify if your show function is being called or not, just place an alert for test

Comment: $scope.searchText = " ";

$scope.show = function()
{
    $scope.great = $scope.searchText;
}